# IF function with two cell ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range

I have two sheets with the same line of cells, for example, **A1:A5**.
I need to check if the value of every cell in **Sheet1!A1:A5** is equal to **Sheet2!A1:A5** but the hitch is the values will be letters, and all values are different. Simply typing the formula got me a `#VALUE!` error.

I know I can just write the formula:

```
=IF(Sheet1!A1=Sheet2!A1;1;0)
```

and then simply retype it in a number of cells with different values, but I'm looking for a way to shorten the formula.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To shorten the formula use array function. With that you will be able to check the whole range at once.

```
=IF(AND(Sheet1!A1:A5=Sheet2!A1:A5);1;0)
```

After typing the formula press Ctrl+Shift+Enter instead of just Enter key to confirm array formula.

Comment: Okay, sir, you are a genius.
Or maybe I wrote the answer inappropriately... Anyway, kudos!

Answer (score 0):

This one is a little shorter

```
=(Sheet1!$A1=Sheet2!$A1)
```

Comment: It works fine, but still, is there a way to merge all five formulas into one?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `AND()` function:

`IF(AND(Sheet1!A1=Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!A2=Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!A3=Sheet2!A3,Sheet1!A4=Sheet2!A4,Sheet1!A5=Sheet2!A5),1,0)`.

**EDIT**

Not realy sure about your aim,

If you want it short because it is too difficult to write the above function, then try the method below:

`=IF(CONCATENATE(Sheet2!A1,Sheet2!B1,Sheet2!C1,Sheet2!D1,Sheet2!E1)=CONCATENATE(Sheet1!A1,Sheet1!B1,Sheet1!C1,Sheet1!D1,Sheet1!E1),1,0)`

But this is not without catch, it could return false positive. So use it with care. To overcome the false positive, I could only make the formula longer (but still relatively easy to write out).

`=IF(CONCATENATE(Sheet2!A1,"|",Sheet2!B1,"|",Sheet2!C1,"|",Sheet2!D1,"|",Sheet2!E1)=CONCATENATE(Sheet1!A1,"|",Sheet1!B1,"|",Sheet1!C1,"|",Sheet1!D1,"|",Sheet1!E1),1,0)`

Comment: I hope shortness is not your ultimate aim, but rather easier way to write the formula... please see my edited answer.

Comment: I guess, this will do the trick, thanks. I don't know about the version differences, but in MS Office 2013 you have to split them with semicolons instead of commas.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
AND(EXACT(Sheet1!A1, Sheet2!A1), EXACT(Sheet1!A2, Sheet2!A2), EXACT(Sheet1!A3, Sheet2!A3), EXACT(Sheet1!A4, Sheet2!A4), EXACT(Sheet1!A5, Sheet2!A5))
```

But in the following way:

1. Have a separate column with the code (let's say, column G)

   ```
   EXACT(Sheet1!$A1, Sheet2!$A2)
   ```
2. To the column next to that, have a single cell with the code

   ```
   AND(G1:G5)
   ```